# show that $(x^b+y^b)^{1/b} < (x^a+y^a)^{1/a}$ if $x>0$, $y>0$, and $0<a<b$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

Show that $(x^b+y^b)^{1/b} < (x^a+y^a)^{1/a}$  if $x>0$, $y>0$,and  $0<a<b$ by examining  the sign of the derivative of an appropriate function.

This is an exercise in middle part of Calculus Vol.1,and I still haven't been much involved in multiple variable problem.

I put both sides in logarithm,since both sides are positive and by the monotonity of logarithm it won't change the sign. So I construct a function $$ f(x,y) = \frac{1}{a} \log(x^a+y^a) - \frac{1}{b} \log(x^b+y^b)\quad (x>0,y>0,0<a<b) $$ and check the partial derivative $f_x$
$$\begin{align} f_x &= \frac{1}{a} \frac{ax^{a-1}}{x^a+y^a}-\frac{1}{b} \frac{bx^{b-1}}{x^b+y^b} 
\\ &= \frac{1}{x} (\frac{x^{a}}{x^a+y^a}-  \frac{x^{b}}{x^b+y^b} ) 
\\&= \frac{1}{x} (\frac{1}{1+ (\frac{y}{x})^a}-  \frac{1}{1+ (\frac{y}{x})^b}) 
\\&= \frac{1}{x} \frac{(\frac{y}{x})^b-(\frac{y}{x})^a}{(1+ (\frac{y}{x})^a)(1+ (\frac{y}{x})^b)) }
\end{align}$$
So this lead to another function $(\frac{y}{x})^b-(\frac{y}{x})^a$ that contain multiple variable,I think I'm not doing it in a right way and now I'm stuck, any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

**Progress:**

I take the advise commented by r9m and covert the problem to single variable by checking the derivative of $T(s)=(x^s+y^s)^{1/s}$,I use the logarithm differential to get 
$$\begin{align}  \frac{T'(s)}{T(s)} 
&= ( \frac{log(x^s+y^s)}{s})'   
\\ &= \frac{a^slog \frac{a^s}{a^s+b^s}+b^slog \frac{b^s}{a^s+b^s}}{s^2(a^s+b^s)} \end{align}$$
So it's a decreasing function for $s>0$. Really appreciate the help from r9m.

Comment: its a single variable problem only, try to show that $T(s)=(x^s+y^s)^{\frac{1}{s}}$ is a decreasing function :)

Comment: Wow,this is a great hint.